# Custom sort doesn't work using primeng p-datatable

Tags: angular, sorting, primeng, primeng-datatable

I have datatable in angular 4 application using PrimeNG and I want to sort by date named as  `received_at`

I already created stackblitz and posted code what I have tried in this

[stackbiltz link - PrimeNG datatable](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ssgajk?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

below PrimeNG datatable grid

```
<p-dataTable [value]="interactionHistories" sortField="received_at">
  <p-column field="case_number" header="Case Number"></p-column>
  <p-column field="received_at" sortable="custom" (sortFunction)="sortByDate($event)" header="Case Date">
    <ng-template let-col let-car="rowData" let-ri="rowIndex" pTemplate="body">
      <span>{{car[col.field] | date: 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss '}}</span>
    </ng-template>
  </p-column>
  <p-column field="status" header="Status"></p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and I solved it using a temporary array. I sorted the rows in that array, I reinitialized the original array and filled it with the temporary rows.

```
sortByDate(event) {
  const tmp = this.interactionHistories.sort((a: any, b: any): number => {
            if (event.field) {
                return a[event.field] > b[event.field] ? 1 : -1;
            }
        });

  if (event.order < 0) {
      tmp.reverse();
  }

  const thisRef = this;
  this.interactionHistories = [];
  tmp.forEach(function (row: any) {
      thisRef.interactionHistories.push(row);
  });

}
```

There might be a better solution but it works.

[Working Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uebjes)

Comment: the real trick here is to have [sortable]="custom" as an attribute to the p-column